# Increase Active Flexibility

Tags: exercise, flexibility, yoga, gymnastics

I am able to do the Front and Side splits (on the floor and against a wall).

However, when just lifting my leg up in front extended casually from standing position, the most I can get it up is 90 degrees. Many ladies are able to extend their leg up much higher than hip level. eg, many cheerleaders and other gymnastics.

how do I increase my resting flexibility similar to photos below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean when you are lifting the leg yourself, or when someone is lifting the leg for you?

Comment: lifting leg by myself no help, @Alec I think its called active flexibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active flexibility is the combination of static flexibility in the muscle being stretched, and isometric strength at short muscle lengths in the antagonist of that muscle.

So if you have the required static flexibility, then antagonist strength is what's limiting you. I'd suggest two forms of training for this:

- Attempting to perform the leg raises, and just holding your leg at whatever height you can reach, aiming to gradually increase that height.
- Attempting to strengthen the antagonist in its fully shortened position, by putting the leg in the stretched position and then attempting to use the antagonist to further stretch it. E.g. raise your leg up onto a wall or sufficiently tall object so that the object, rather than your own muscular strength, is holding your leg up. Then use your muscles to try to raise your leg even higher and lift it off the object. (Your leg won't actually move, but hopefully you'll feel less pressure between it and the object supporting it as you try to raise it.)

Answer (score -4):

Problems with your Iliopsoas muscle
The muscle that brings your foot closer to your pelvis
A few simple exercises will help you achieve the desired result

1. Navasana state
2. supta padangusthasana 1

Comment: I don't understand this answer

Comment: these are a yoga pose . you can do it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdF9oN-zU0U and here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVEINjrYUPU